# echo content of file which contains executable scripts in bash

Tags: bash, shell, echo, cat

when I write to console e.g. this:

```
echo -e "directory content: \n $(ls -l)"
```

I'll get something like this:

```
directory content:
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user    0 Apr  9 10:28 file.txt
```

That's OK, but I want to have "directory content: \n $(ls -l)" in one file and write bash script where will be that file read and echo it's content with executed scripts to another file.

I wrote this simple script

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$(<file.txt)
echo -e "$FILE"
```

Unfortunately cat probably escapes characters, so after execution I got this

```
directory content: 
 $(ls -l)
```

Is there a way how to get proper result?

Comment: @tuxuday: Literally `directory content: \n $(ls -l)`, as far as I could figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
bash-3.2$ cat file.txt
directory content: \\n $(ls -l)


bash-3.2$ MYFILE=$(<file.txt)
bash-3.2$ eval echo -e "$MYFILE"
directory content:
 total 8 -rw-r--r-- 1 fti staff 32 09 avr 12:40 file.txt
```

Not sure if best practice though.

Answer (score 1):

```
FILE=$(<file.txt)
```

This puts the literal contents of `file.txt` into `FILE`. From that point onward, the contents of `file.txt` -- including the `$()` part -- are considered a string, nothing more. The reason you do not get `ls` executed is not some escaping of characters, but the fact that there is no execution of the contents of `FILE` involved.

What you want -- the *execution* of the *contents* of a string -- is commonly considered a glaring security leak (since your script does not have full control over the contents of `file.txt`, i.e. is open to code injection). Perl for example allows this explicitly via `eval`; <del>I know of no such feature for bash</del> apparently (as [fredtantini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22960101/60281) points out) this is possible for bash as well... +1 to him. (Though I am quite sure this is *not* best practice for the reasons given.)

Answer (score 0):

You are conflating code with data: don't do that. Instead, make a shell script and source or execute it.

```
$ cat file.sh
echo directory content:
ls -l

$ . file.sh
directory content:
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user    0 Apr  9 10:28 file.txt

$ MYFILE=$( bash file.sh )
$ echo "$MYFILE"
directory content:
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user    0 Apr  9 10:28 file.txt
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I want. Main purpose of that txt file is documentation. For example I want to document program and this documentation should contain list of files. But in short future can be more files added and I don't want to edit documentation manually, but simple run script which regenerate it. I'm not sure if I explain it clearly.

Comment: You probably want to look into using a proper documentation generation system that supports this kind of templating, rather than trying to hack something in `bash`.